# Crucible 2.7 - update all outdated files in a review

Tags: atlassian-crucible

Right now, to update the outdated files in my crucible review, I navigate to individual files, see if the file is outdated(by looking out for 'File Outdated' link) and then add the latest revision to the review if I were the author/moderator. I'll like to know if I could update all the outdated files in a review in one click assuming I'm aware of what I do.

I did read into their docs about this, but there was no mention of such a thing. Do you all update the files individually as well? Any plugins out there that could help me update all outdated files in my crucible review?

Comment: Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: That feature is missing -- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-5869